# How to telnet checkpoint firewalls using python?

Tags: python, networking, automation

I want to check whether the console for the checkpoint firewalls is working or not which python Library should I use and how to use?

I tried telnetlib but was unable to find the correct output

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that can helps you but maybe you can try **pwntools** or use directly **socket** module.

**pwntools** (you can connect to an endpoint using ssh or telnet and then run an interactive shell) :

- https://pypi.org/project/pwntools/
- https://docs.pwntools.com/en/stable/install.html

**socket** :

- https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sockets.html

Comment: could you please help me with an example

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried netmiko package?
https://ktbyers.github.io/netmiko/docs/netmiko/checkpoint/index.html

I have no experience with Checkpoint, but similar code for other network devices is working

```
ssh = ConnectHandler(host="hostname",
                     username="user",
                     password="password",
                     device_type="checkpoint_gaia")
output = ssh.send_command("show version all")
print(output)
```